# Django Saving files in database with username

Tags: python, django

I am getting multiple file entries from the user. And I save all of these in the database in one go.

But I don't want these files to get mixed up when multiple users use the system. Therefore, when I save each file, I want the username that uploaded that file to be saved in the database.

**Models.py**

```
class users(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=True, verbose_name="name")
    person_surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=True, verbose_name="surname")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True, verbose_name='email')
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=True, verbose_name="username")
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=False, blank=True, verbose_name="password")


class files(models.Model):
    owner= models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, related_name="owner", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    excelFile = models.FileField(upload_to='upload/%Y/%m/%d',null=False, blank=True,)

    wordFile = models.FileField(upload_to='upload/%Y/%m/%d',null=False, blank=True,)
    
    txtEmailFile = models.FileField(upload_to='upload/%Y/%m/%d',null=False, blank=True,)
     
    txtContentFile = models.FileField(upload_to='upload/%Y/%m/%d',null=False, blank=True,)

    attachmentFile = models.FileField(upload_to='upload/%Y/%m/%d',null=False, blank=True,)
```

**forms.py**

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = files
        fields = ('description', 'excelFile', 'wordFile', 'txtEmailFile', 'txtContentFile', 'attachmentFile')
```

**views.py ( only one func ):**

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def sendmail(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('sendmail')

        else:
            form = DocumentForm()

    return render(request, 'sendmail.html')
```

I am not adding the html file here because I received multiple file entries from the user and the html file is mixed.

**Database ( MySql Workbench ):**
[image]

How can I do it ?

Comment: It seems your DB is empty

Comment: Please clarify, do you want username to appear in the path of the uploaded file, or do you have problem to get current user in  `DocumentForm`?

Comment: Because I haven't added any data yet. I can add if I want @JLeno46

Comment: When saving files, I want to record which user uploaded these files to the files uploaded at once, so that there is no confusion in retrieving these files from the database in the future. @datosula

Comment: If you want username somehow to appear in saved file path, be it as a separate folder, for each user, or username in the file name, you could use callable as value to FileField's upload_to  parameter, and this callable will be called each time Django needs to generate path/filename for the uploaded file. Please, see [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) for more. It'll have `instance` parameter from which you can access `user_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':        
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.owner = request.user
        instance.save()
        return redirect('sendmail')
```

You can save an instance without commit modify one or more fields, and then save and commit.

Comment: Thanks so much, what you showed did and it worked. But when saving the owner_id, it is saving 1 more than the actual user id value. What is the reason?

Comment: It may be because your owner attribute  refers to a different class than your users class.

Comment: Understood. So does it create a problem?

Comment: I am getting an error. After uploading files for each user, I cannot upload files with the same user again.
Error message: (1062, "Duplicate entry '2' for key 'mailsystem_files.owner_id'") @JLeno46

Comment: because it's an OneToOne relationship, a User can upload just 1 file, a file can be owned by 1 User. If you want a User to own more files change OneToOne in your model with Foreignkey. Check ManyToOne relationship here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/